# What's the difference between '{"title":"some title", "body":"some body"}' and '{"title":title, "body":body}', when title and body are string values?

Tags: python, python-requests

Code below works:

```
r = requests.post(url = myurl, data = '{"title":"sometitle", "body":"some body"}')
```

But this code doesn't work:

```
t = "title"   
b = "body"   
r = requests.post(url = myurl, data = '{"title":title, "body":body}')
```

The second one causes 400 error.
I can't find any meaningful difference.
What I changed is just replacing " " string to a string value.

According to requests doc, data is

> data – (optional) Dictionary, list of tuples, bytes, or file-like
>   object to send in the body of the Request.

I have to get some values and store them into variables, so I need to make the code in the second way.
How can I resolve this?

[image]

Comment: The latter isn't valid JSON? If you want to put the *values* into the string, pass an actual dictionary `{'title': t, 'body': b}`; `requests` can handle that for you, or you can use `json.stringify`.

Comment: probably you wanted `'{"title":t, "body":b}'`, but even with this it won't work (you're trying to access variables within string body).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Even when I try 
dict = {'title':t, 'body':b}
data = dict
  This doesn't work, either. Is this what 'an actual dictionary' means?

Comment: Yes, that's an actual dictionary; what do you mean *"doesn't work"*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe That also causes a 400 error.

Comment: `requests` should handle posting a dictionary just fine, see [the examples](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request). You'll have to give a [mre] to illustrate the problem; what's *receiving* that data?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I attached a terminal capture in the question. It goes like that.

Comment: And what if you try `data = json.dumps(dict)`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh, yeah it works! Thanks jonrsharpe :) This really bothered, and you really helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> data – (optional) Dictionary, list of tuples, bytes, or file-like object to send in the body of the Request.

In both cases you are not passing a dictionary. You are passing a string both times.

> ```
> r = requests.post(url = myurl, data = '{"title":"sometitle", "body":"some body"}')
> ```

This is a dictionary parsed into a string.

> ```
> t = "title"   
> b = "body"   
> r = requests.post(url = myurl, data = '{"title":title, "body":body}')
> ```

This is a non-valid dictionary parsed into a string. You probably meant to write:

```
t = "title"   
b = "body"   
r = requests.post(url = myurl, data = {"title":title, "body":body})
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
r = requests.post(url = myurl, data = {"title":"title", "body":"body"})
```

Here you would be passing a dictionary and you can also reference variables. It is not a string you are passing.

If you require the data to be in a string format (which doesn't make sense since the documentation you referenced says it requires a dictionary) you do:

```
t = "title"   
b = "body"   
r = requests.post(url = myurl, data = json.dumps({"title":title, "body":body}))
```